# POST-запрос на Kotlin, android

Tags: android, kotlin, post

Пытаюсь отправить post-запрос с данными qr-кода на сайт проверки чека и вытянуть из него дату и общую сумму. Когда отправляю с помощью Postman, всё окей:
[image: скриншот из Postman с body запроса]

С тестовыми данными возвращает json вида:

```
{
    "code": 1,
    "data": {
        "json": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "sum": 42000,
                    "name": "S18EDEAT008-2C 5 Мяч футбольный, р.5 Soccer Ball, size 5 бежевый р.5",
                    "price": 42000,
                    "ndsSum": 7000,
                    "ndsRate": 1,
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "calculationSubjectSign": 1
                },
                {
                    "sum": 2800,
                    "name": "EBM-C Батончик злаковый черника ENERGON Muesli bar р.NS",
                    "price": 2800,
                    "ndsSum": 467,
                    "ndsRate": 1,
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "calculationSubjectSign": 1
                },
                {
                    "sum": 2800,
                    "name": "EBM-Y Батончик злаковый яблоко ENERGON Muesli bar р.NS",
                    "price": 2800,
                    "ndsSum": 467,
                    "ndsRate": 1,
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "calculationSubjectSign": 1
                }
            ],
            "nds18": 7934,
            "userInn": "7728551528",
            "dateTime": "2019-02-02T10:44:00",
            "kktRegId": "0000568475062805    ",
            "operator": "КАССИР: Незлобина Ирина",
            "totalSum": 47600,
            "fiscalSign": 399448105,
            "operatorInn": "220805277028",
            "receiptCode": 3,
            "shiftNumber": 220,
            "cashTotalSum": 47600,
            "taxationType": 1,
            "ecashTotalSum": 0,
            "operationType": 1,
            "prepaymentSum": 0,
            "requestNumber": 4,
            "postpaymentSum": 0,
            "protocolVersion": 2,
            "fiscalDriveNumber": "9289000100054082",
            "counterSubmissionSum": 0,
            "fiscalDocumentNumber": 16112
        },
        "html": "<table class=\"b-check_table table\"><tbody><tr class=\"b-check_vblock-middle b-check_center\"><td colspan=\"5\">ИНН 7728551528</td></tr><tr class=\"b-check_vblock-middle b-check_center\"><td colspan=\"5\">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class=\"b-check_vblock-middle b-check_center\"><td colspan=\"5\">02.02.2019 10:44</td></tr><tr class=\"b-check_vblock-middle b-check_center\"><td colspan=\"5\">Чек № 4</td></tr><tr class=\"b-check_vblock-middle b-check_center\"><td colspan=\"5\">Смена № 220</td></tr><tr class=\"b-check_vblock-middle b-check_center\"><td colspan=\"5\">Кассир КАССИР: Незлобина Ирина</td></tr><tr class=\"b-check_vblock-last b-check_center\"><td colspan=\"5\">Приход</td></tr><tr><td><strong>№</strong></td><td><strong>Название</strong></td><td><strong>Цена</strong></td><td><strong>Кол.</strong></td><td><strong>Сумма</strong></td></tr><tr class=\"b-check_item\"><td>1</td><td>S18EDEAT008-2C 5 Мяч футбольный, р.5 Soccer Ball, size 5 бежевый р.5</td><td>420.00</td><td>1</td><td>420.00</td></tr><tr class=\"b-check_item\"><td>2</td><td>EBM-C Батончик злаковый черника ENERGON Muesli bar р.NS</td><td>28.00</td><td>1</td><td>28.00</td></tr><tr class=\"b-check_item\"><td>3</td><td>EBM-Y Батончик злаковый яблоко ENERGON Muesli bar р.NS</td><td>28.00</td><td>1</td><td>28.00</td></tr><tr class=\"b-check_vblock-first\"><td colspan=\"3\" class=\"b-check_itogo\">ИТОГО:</td><td></td><td class=\"b-check_itogo\">476.00</td></tr><tr class=\"b-check_vblock-middle\"><td colspan=\"3\">Наличные</td><td></td><td>476.00</td></tr><tr class=\"b-check_vblock-middle\"><td colspan=\"3\">Карта</td><td></td><td>0.00</td></tr><tr class=\"b-check_vblock-middle\"><td colspan=\"3\">НДС итога чека со ставкой 20%</td><td></td><td>79.34</td></tr><tr class=\"b-check_vblock-last\"><td colspan=\"5\">ВИД НАЛОГООБЛОЖЕНИЯ: ОСН</td></tr><tr class=\"b-check_vblock-first\"><td colspan=\"5\">РЕГ.НОМЕР ККТ: 0000568475062805    </td></tr><tr class=\"b-check_vblock-middle\"><td colspan=\"5\">ЗАВОД. №: </td></tr><tr class=\"b-check_vblock-middle\"><td colspan=\"5\">ФН: 9289000100054082</td></tr><tr class=\"b-check_vblock-middle\"><td colspan=\"5\">ФД: 16112</td></tr><tr class=\"b-check_vblock-middle\"><td colspan=\"5\">ФПД#: 399448105</td></tr><tr class=\"b-check_vblock-last\"><td colspan=\"5\" class=\"b-check_center\"><img src=\"/qrcode/generate?text=t%3D20190202T1044%26s%3D476.00%26fn%3D9289000100054082%26i%3D16112%26fp%3D399448105%26n%3D1\" alt=\"QR код чека\" width=\"35%\" loading=\"lazy\" decoding=\"async\"></td></tr></tbody></table>"
    }
}
```

Пробовала retrofit, не помогло (возможно, пробовала неправильно), сейчас код выглядит так:

```
                val qrCodes: SparseArray<Barcode> = detections.detectedItems
                val code = qrCodes.valueAt(0)
                val client = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                    .build()
                val mediaType = "text/plain".toMediaType()
                val token: String = "4483.c56QLvFekVokj1uCW"
                val dataSend: String = "token=" + token + "&"+ code.displayValue
                val body: RequestBody = dataSend.toRequestBody(mediaType)

                val request: Request = Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://proverkacheka.com/api/v1/check/get")
                    .method("POST", body)
                    .addHeader("Host", "proverkacheka.com")
                    .addHeader("Cookie", "ENGID=1.1")
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
                    .build()
                val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
                val json = response.body?.string()
                val sum = (JSONObject(json).getJSONObject("data").get("totalSum")).toString()
                val dateTime = (JSONObject(json).getJSONObject("data").get("dateTime")).toString()
```

В ответ приходит ошибка - "Вы не авторизовались". Не могу понять, в чём дело, ведь токен я тоже отправляю.
Надеюсь, кто-нибудь сможет помочь, впервые сюда пишу, уже совсем отчаялась.

Comment: Кажется, дело в том, что у вас второй параметр запроса не имеет имени параметра и знака равно, что сервером считывается как продолжение значения параметра токена и в итоге токен признаётся невалидным.

Comment: В постмане вы отправляете form-data, а в коде `text/plain` (простым текстом). Вам нужно выяснить какой формат запроса поддерживает сервер и дальше смотреть доку/пример как такой формат отправить из ретрофита